# Remove field to get the value using awk or sed

Tags: unix, awk, grep

I have a text file with following data.

```
            \ {
                Name     "ABC",
                count   378
            }
            \ {
                Name     "DEF",
                count   5283
            }
            \ {
                Name     "BCD",
                count   152244
            }
            \ {
                Name     "XYZ",
                count   5688
            }
            \ {
                Name     "1A2B",
                count   1749132
            }
```

I want the result like  :--

```
            ABC , 378
            DEF , 5283
            BCD , 152244
            XYZ , 5688
            1A2B ,1749132
```

I tried to remove the non revelant data using the command :--

```
            grep -e '^ ' result.txt
```

But I am unable to proceed beyond it . Can someone help me with same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try following awk and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '/Name/{gsub(/\"|\,/,"",$2);val=$2;next} /count/{print val " , " $2}'  Input_file
```

OR

```
awk -F'[",]' '/Name/{val=$2;next} /count/{split($0, a," ");print val,a[2]}' OFS=" , "  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another `awk` thought you may apply,

```
$ awk '$2~/[0-9A-Z]/ {printf gsub(/"/,"",$2)?$2:" "$2"\n"}' file
```

Brief explanation,

- `$2~/[0-9A-Z]/`: find the record matched regex `[0-9A-Z]`
- `gsub(/"/,"",$2)`: remove `"` in the `$2`, and then print it

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an awk that supports regular expression `RS` (at least gawk and mawk), you can do it like this:

```
awk '!(NR%2) { print $3 " , " $5  }' RS='\\ *{|}' FS='[\n," ]+' infile
```

Output:

```
ABC , 378
DEF , 5283
BCD , 152244
XYZ , 5688
1A2B , 1749132
```

Answer (score 0):

***sed*** solution:

```
sed -En '/[{}]/d;N; s/Name *"([^"]+)".*count *([0-9]+).*/\1 , \2/p;' file
```

The output:

```
        ABC , 378
        DEF , 5283
        BCD , 152244
        XYZ , 5688
        1A2B , 1749132
```